# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10 for Inventory

Tags: java, arrays, windows, applet, indexoutofboundsexception

I have been following a tutorial online on making a 2D game but hope to expand on it. Everything has been working up to the point when I try moving items around in an inventory. I can successfully pick up items and place them back down onto the invBar, but it will not allow me to place them into the inventory invBag. I have followed everything that he went over but for some reason he did not get the error.

I am a beginning coder and so far I understand that this error is created by the array going "out of bounds" (as the title of the error obviously mentions) but I do not understand "how" it is going out of bounds.

Edit: GAWD I am an idiot... for some reason I have been typing 1 instead of i for some dum reason, and apparently that was the problem.

Code for Inventory:

```
package y.m.m //to protect project name

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Inventory {
public static Cell[] invBar = new Cell[Tile.invLength];
public static Cell[] invBag = new Cell[Tile.invLength * Tile.invHeight];

public static boolean isOpen = false;
public static boolean isHolding = false;

public static int selected = 0;
public static int[] holdingID = Tile.air;
public static int holdingCount = 0;

public Inventory() {
    for(int i = 0; i < invBar.length; i++) {
        invBar[i] = new Cell(new Rectangle((Component.pixel.width / 2) - ((Tile.invLength * (Tile.invCellSize + Tile.invCellSpace))/2) + (i * (Tile.invCellSize + Tile.invCellSpace)), Component.pixel.height - (Tile.invCellSize + Tile.invBorderSpace), Tile.invCellSize, Tile.invCellSize), Tile.air);
    }

    int x = 0, y = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < invBag.length; i++) {
        invBag[i] = new Cell(new Rectangle((Component.pixel.width / 2) - ((Tile.invLength * (Tile.invCellSize + Tile.invCellSpace))/2) + (x * (Tile.invCellSize + Tile.invCellSpace)), Component.pixel.height - (Tile.invCellSize + Tile.invBorderSpace) - (Tile.invHeight * (Tile.invCellSize + Tile.invCellSpace)) + (y * (Tile.invCellSize + Tile.invCellSpace)), Tile.invCellSize, Tile.invCellSize), Tile.air);

        x++;
        if(x == Tile.invLength) {
            x = 0;
            y++;
        }
    }

    invBar[0].id = Tile.sand;
    invBar[1].id = Tile.grass;
    invBar[2].id = Tile.dirt;
    invBar[3].id = Tile.bush;
}

public static void click(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getButton() == 1) {
        if(isOpen) {
            for(int i = 0; 1 < invBar.length; i++) {
            Line 43 > if(invBar[i].contains(new Point(Component.mse.x / Component.pixelSize, Component.mse.y / Component.pixelSize))) {
                    if(invBar[i].id != Tile.air && !isHolding) {
                        holdingID = invBar[i].id;
                        invBar[i].id = Tile.air;

                        isHolding = true;
                    } else if(isHolding && invBar[i].id == Tile.air) {
                        invBar[i].id = holdingID;

                        isHolding = false;
                    } else if(isHolding && invBar[i].id != Tile.air) {
                        int[] con = invBar[i].id;
                        invBar[i].id = holdingID;
                        holdingID = con;
                    }
                }
            }


            for(int i = 0; 1 < invBag.length; i++) {
                if(invBag[i].contains(new Point(Component.mse.x / Component.pixelSize, Component.mse.y / Component.pixelSize))) {
                    if(invBag[i].id != Tile.air && !isHolding) {
                        holdingID = invBag[i].id;
                        invBag[i].id = Tile.air;    

                        isHolding = true;
                    } else if(isHolding && invBag[i].id == Tile.air) {
                        invBag[i].id = holdingID;   

                        isHolding = false;
                    } else if(isHolding && invBag[i].id != Tile.air) {
                        int[] con = invBag[i].id;

                        invBag[i].id = holdingID;
                        holdingID = con;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void render(Graphics g) {
    for(int i = 0; i < invBar.length; i++) {
        boolean isSelected = false;
        if(i == selected) {
            isSelected = true;
        }

        invBar[i].render(g, isSelected);
    }

    if(isOpen) {
        //g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        for(int i = 0;i < invBag.length; i++) {
            invBag[i].render(g, false);
        }
    }

    if(isHolding) {
        // [- (Tile.invCellSize / 2)] centers item to mouse
        g.drawImage(Tile.tileset_terrain, (Component.mse.x / Component.pixelSize) - (Tile.invCellSize / 2) + Tile.invItemBorder, (Component.mse.y / Component.pixelSize) - (Tile.invCellSize / 2) + Tile.invItemBorder, (Component.mse.x / Component.pixelSize) - (Tile.invCellSize / 2) + Tile.invCellSize - Tile.invItemBorder, (Component.mse.y / Component.pixelSize) - (Tile.invCellSize / 2) + Tile.invCellSize - Tile.invItemBorder, holdingID[0] * Tile.tileSize, holdingID[1] * Tile.tileSize, holdingID[0] * Tile.tileSize + Tile.tileSize, holdingID[1] * Tile.tileSize + Tile.tileSize, null);
    }
}
}
```

Chunk from Listening that is mentioned:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        Component.isMseLeft = true;
    } else if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
        Component.isMseRight = true;
    }

Line 158 > Inventory.click(e);
}
```

The error that is generated:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
at y.m.m.Inventory.click(Inventory.java:43)
at y.m.m.Listening.mousePressed(Listening.java:158)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6502)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop you have

```
int i = 0; 1 < invBag.length; i++
```

since `1 < invBag.length`  is always true , Hence IndexOutOfBoundException